# How to place asterisks in beginning and end of lines in a marked region?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I use `org-mode` a a lot and take notes in Org files. I like to sometimes highlight some important text. I colored *bold* to be red but it doesn't span multiple lines. And I couldn't get that to work using multiple stackexchange solutions. So I opted to mark the lines I want to boldify with asterisks. But that is taking time. How would I implement a function in Elisp that does that for me automatically.

Basically in this snippet of text:

```
This is a test to make sure I can []highlight some text in org-mode
And hopefully someone would be able to help me.[]
```

Now if I highlighted the region between [] [] and then use the function, the text will change to:

```
This is a test to make sure I can *highlight some text in org-mode*
*And hopefully someone would be able to help me.*
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Bold marked region in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315534/bold-marked-region-in-org-mode/14317912)

Comment: Juancho, applying org-emphasize is not working for me when the text spans multiple lines. It only places a star at the beginning and end of text but it does not boldify it.

Comment: I use the code here: https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org.el#L665

to do what you describe.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using that same package (ov-highlighter) since it does exactly what I want.